# Directed to undirected graph in Networkx results in disconected graph

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I am trying to calculate the current flow centrality of directed graphs with networkx. It seems the method transforms the directed graph into undirected graph internally, and the method prints an error saying my graph is disconnected. Before calling the current flow betweenness centrality method I am removing isolated nodes. How come when transforming it to undirected it becomes disconnected? Is there anything I can do so it does not happen? For example transform the graph somehow?

```
nx.current_flow_betweenness_centrality( nx_graph )
```

Furthermore, when I try to manually transform my graph into undirected and check if it is connected it returns false.

```
check_graph.remove_nodes_from( list(nx.isolates(check_graph)) )
print("nx.is_connected(check_graph)", nx.is_connected(check_graph))
```

Answer (score 1):

The funtion current_flow_betweenness_centrality of NetworkX operates on undirected graphs. As you apply this function to a directed graph, it internally converts the graph to an undirected graph before performing the computation. However, this process might not guarantee the connectivity of the resulting undirected graph.

While converting a directed graph to an undirected graph might cause inconsistencies in terms of connectivity, especially if the original directed graph had disconnected components.
I would recommend to check first if the original graph is connected, create an object for the undirected graph of the original graph by the DiGraph.to_undirected(reciprocal=False, as_view=False) function, see https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.DiGraph.to_undirected.html and then calculate the flow.

Comment: yes, the original directed graph is connected. The code I provided does what you are suggesting and returns false. Meaning the graph is connected when directed and becomes disconnected when transformed to undirected.